# Angular: Can't use ng-Command

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli

I'm trying to install angular in a vagrant-box.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Sadly I get this error when I try using the client:

```
The program 'ng' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install ng-common
```

(ng-common seems to be a text-editor?)

does anyone know how I can get this running?

I tryied uninstalling and reinstalling.

Edits:
Im running Ubuntu in the vagrant-box and I'm working only inside of it.
The installation is completed even though I'm skipping two optional dependencys.

Comment: what exactly do you run, what's your OS? Do you run it inside the vagrant box or outside? Was the installation of angular-cli complete successfully?

Comment: edited my question to account for these questions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the issue:

I had installed two diffrent versions of angular-cli:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
npm install -g angular-cli
```

The second line installs an older version which creates a conflict.
You can check which versions are installed with this line:

```
npm list -g --depth=0
```

I wasn't able to "*npm uninstall*" it, so I remove it with "*sudo rm*" from the node folder.

Finally I added the path (this will work no matter where ur node is):

```
echo -e "export PATH=$(npm prefix -g)/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue after installation `npm install -g @angular/cli` caused by the incorrect [**version**](https://angular.io/guide/quickstart#nodejs) of the node.

I solved it by using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to manage the node version:

```
nvm list; # check your local versions;
nvm install 10.10.0; # install a new remote version;
nvm alias default 10.10.0; # set the 10.10.0 as the default node version, but you have to restart the terminal to make it take effect;

nvm list; # make sure you are using the right version;
nvm use default; # if not
```

Then you don't even need to **reinstall** angular, check it with `ng -h` and it will work.